# update my table when putting a score

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there i have created a table but when i am putting the score it is not updated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTable(){    
  document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = '';    
  var firstdropbox = document.getElementById("first").value;    
  var seconddropbox = document.getElementById("second").value;    
  var box1 = Number(document.getElementById("txtbox1").value);    
  var box2 = Number(document.getElementById("txtbox2").value);    
  var a = Number(document.getElementById(firstdropbox).innerHTML);    
  var b = Number(document.getElementById(seconddropbox).innerHTML);   

  if(firstdropbox==seconddropbox){    
    alert("Must select two different teams..");
    return false;    
  }
  if(a>6){    
    alert("Can play only 7 matches");   
    return false;    
  }        
  if(firstdropbox != seconddropbox){            
    document.getElementById(firstdropbox).innerHTML = a + 1;   
    document.getElementById(seconddropbox).innerHTML = b + 1;
  }     
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `document.getElementById(firstdropbox).innerHTML` is returning numeric text? You may want to provide the HTML which goes along with this script so people can help. Better yet, consider reducing the html and javascript to the least amound which shows the error and post it to a place like jsfiddle.net.

Comment: yes it is returning numeric but the problem here is that i think i must put my headers is an array so as i can locate them to place the values in my table but i don't know how to do it